# Does a script cloning private repo need credentials of the user?

Tags: git, gitlab

My understanding is that if an employee setups up a script that clones a private repo from gitlab, he would have to put his private-key in the script and there should be a corresponding public-key in his gitlab account. So the process is connected to a particular user.

What happens if that employee leaves the company? Do we have to create another user on gitlab with new public-key, and change the private key the in script? Is there any way to do this without creating a new user?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/

Comment: This should be a thing of discussion. First of all why should a private repo be of interest to the company? If you are dependent on the private repo of individuals then it's just bad. If privacy is what concerns you then you should instead have such repos  created under a separate organization. Not sure how it works in GitLab, but something similar to GitHub organization where you can decide who the owners will be and also get a service account created. That way you could use the service account instead and perform token based authorizations.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick The repo is private to the world. Other users of the company in gitlab can clone and make changes to the repo using their credentials.

Comment: just a pointer : If company associates are able to access it as you say, then it might be an `internal` repo and not `private`.